# Tensorflow real example

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've a wrote a code based on this  [Tensorflow example](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners)  . the  issue that I'm having is that accuracy that I get doesn't make any sense ( it' either 1 or 0 )  so my question is what I'm missing here?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import  numpy as np
import  csv
import os


#defining  batch fuuntion

def batch(iterable, n=1):
    l = len(iterable)
    for ndx in range(0, l, n):
        yield iterable[ndx:min(ndx + n, l)]


os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
Training_File = 'Training.csv'
Test_File     = 'Test.csv'
numberOFClasses = 19
batchSize = 19

# read training data
filePointer  = open(Training_File, 'r', newline='')
reader = csv.reader(filePointer)
Training_Data   = []
Training_Labels = []
row = next(reader)
len(row)
#### Getting Training_Data and labels
for  row in reader:
    Training_Data.append(row[:-2])
    Training_Labels.append(row[-1])
# close TrainingFile  and  getting Data and labels from Test
len(Training_Data)
filePointer.close();

filePointer =open(Test_File, 'r', newline='')
reader  =   csv.reader(filePointer)
Test_Data = []
Test_Labels=[]
row = next(reader)

for row in reader:
    Test_Data.append(row[:-2])
    Test_Labels.append(row[-1])
len(Test_Labels)
filePointer.close()
len(Training_Data[0])



x = tf.placeholder('float',[None,len(row[:-2])])
w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([len(row[:-2]),numberOFClasses]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([numberOFClasses]))
model = tf.add(tf.matmul(x,w),b)
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,numberOFClasses])
y =  tf.nn.softmax(model)

cross_entropy= -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y),reduction_indices=[1])
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
index =0
batch_xs = []
batch_ys = []
batch_txs= []
batch_tys= []
# Training processing


for i in batch(Training_Data,batchSize):
    batch_xs.append(i)
for i in batch(Training_Labels,batchSize):
    batch_ys.append(i)

for i in batch(Test_Data,batchSize):
    batch_txs.append(i)
for i in batch(Test_Labels,batchSize):
    batch_tys.append(i)


#print(np.reshape(batch_ys[len],(1,batchSize)))
for i in range(len(batch_xs) -1 ):
    sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x:batch_xs[i],y_:np.reshape(batch_ys[i],(1,batchSize))})



correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.arg_max(y,1),tf.arg_max(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,"float"))
for i in range(len(batch_txs) -1):
    print(sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={x:batch_txs[i],y_:np.reshape(batch_tys[i],(1,batchSize))}))
```

**UPDATE**
I've changed the size of the batches:

```
.............................................
numberOFClasses = 19

batchSize = 19 * 3
....................................
for i in range(int(len(batch_xs)/batchSize) ):
    print(sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x:batch_xs[i],y_:np.reshape(batch_ys[i],(batchSize,numberOFClasses))}))



correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.arg_max(y,1),tf.arg_max(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,"float"))
for i in range(len(batch_txs) -1):
    print(sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={x:batch_txs[i],y_:np.reshape(batch_tys[i],(1,batchSize))}))
```

the result still the same, So I just don't get what I'm missing here

**2ndUpdate**

Running this part of the code :
    for j in range(len(batch_xs)-1):
        print(sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x:batch_xs[j],y_:np.reshape(batch_ys[j],(numberOFClasses,3))}))

delivers a huge error message but I guess this part is relevant :

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [19,3] vs. [57,19]
 [[Node: mul = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_Placeholder_1_0, Log)]]
```

So since my batch size is tree times the number of classes, I should get 57 predictions-> Y_ .

Shaping the feeding of Y_  [57,1]

for j in range(len(batch_xs)-1):
    print(sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x:batch_xs[j],y_:np.reshape(batch_ys[j],(batchSize,1))}))

the print delivers `None` as return value but no error which is (I guess) ok.

But running the accuracy part delivers 1 and 0 as mentioned in the beginning.

the Test and Train Data and labels are 100% correct !

here is part of the end of CSV file :

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure but I feel there s something strange with y_:np.reshape(batch_tys[i],(1,batchSize)): should y_ not be of shape (batch_size, numOfClasses) instead ? Since batch_size == numOfClasses incidently, that may not raise any exception, but just not perform what you think at all, like comparing all y's to the same y_ (not one different per sample)... If your network is not trained enough and outputs always the same class for instance (big biases), it would explain the 0 or 1 accuracy.

Comment: @gdelab  thanks a lot for your comment, here is how I understand the whole thing.  The train data is  X and the predictionS of the training will be put out in Y and I'm using Y_ to evaluate how good the training is by reading the labels from the file. I got your point how may solve this ? by make the batch size bigger ?

Comment: Y_ just needs to be of the right shape... If Y_ is given in 1-hot vectors form (for each sample, so 2-D matrix), then it should be of shape (batch_size, numOfClasses) just like Y, and you only need to change your `reshape`s accordingly in the feed_dicts (to set the shape to (batch_size, numOfClasses)). If it is given as the class index for each sample (1-D vector of length batch_size, containing numbers from 0 to numClasses- 1), then you should change the reshape (to (batch_size, 1)), and replace argmax(y_) by y_.

Comment: And to be sure you don't miss exceptions that could be useful, I suggest you use a batch_size different from numOfClasses , for example 17 and 19.

Comment: Y_ is onehot coded and reshaping is woking for batchsize = numberofClass, and I'm not reading tell the end to avoid exception for now. 
I've tried to change make a bigg batch size but I get shape errors !

Comment: Seeing the last edit: sorry if I'm wrong, but I don't think you understand what a 1-hot coding is. It means that, if you have 2 possible classes A and B, any object of class A will have a code (1,0), and objects of class B will have (0,1). The encoding takes numberOFClasses bits to encode. In your CSV file, you seem to only have one bit (always a 1 as far as we can see), so you can't encode 19 classes with it. For 19 classes, your CSV rows should end with 19 separate numbers for this encoding, with each time one 1 on the spot corresponding to the sample's class and the rest only 0s.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324156/feed-dict-and-numpy-reshape

Comment: for 19 classes I need 19Bits each class is represented by one 1 the last one has 524288 as value which 2^19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be the source of your problem or errors, but I think all occurrences of row[:-2] should be replaced by row[:-1], if you want to take all indices but one (Python excludes the index `end` given in a range like `row[begin:end]`)

You should have:

```
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,numberOFClasses])
...
sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x:batch_xs[i],y_:np.reshape(batch_ys[i],(batchSize, numberOFClasses ))})
...
print(sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={x:batch_txs[i],y_:np.reshape(batch_tys[i],(batchSize, numberOFClasses ))}))
```

Anyway, you should definetly use `batch_size != numberOFClasses`, because it throws an error that you can use to understand what is wrong in your code. If you don't, you lose the exception message but the error is still there, hidden (you network still does not learn what you want). When you get the error look which reshapecauses a problem, and try to understand why (look what the shapes are and should be)

Comment: thanks a lot for your help I'm changing the batch size  and let's see what happens

Comment: and by the way the row[:-2] is correct  the last column is onehot coded and the one before is not

Comment: Sorry I still get weird result or errors I just don't get it, see the question update

Comment: Ok I think I get it. How is your data given exactly ? Like, what is there in the typical row of your CSV ? I think your problem is when you load your data: Training_Labels.append(row[-1]) would mean that your label is written in only 1 slot of your CSV, which is the case if it is not 1-hot encoded. But, if it is, then a label should take numberOFClasses slots, 1 for each class (all equal to 0 except one equal to 1 in each row). Otherwise you need a little bit of code to 'translate' from label index to one-hot form...

Comment: Anyway, as is, your labels are juste of shape (nSamples, 1) when you load them, but then you use them as if they were (nSamples, numberOFClasses ), which they should be if you use 1-hot encoding. So, to know what you should do, you should tell us exactly how exactly the input data is given in your CSV

Comment: I accept your answer because now it's clear to me where the problem is, never the less  I still have a shaping problem

Answer (score 0):

From your code sample it's impossible to tell exactly (at least batch() and batchSize are missing to be sure), but my guess is that you have batches of size one (whether intended or not), and so you get either an accuracy of one (if the sample was predicted correctly) or zero (if the sample was misclassified). For meaningful accuracies, you want to evaluate over larger batches.

Comment: thanks for you reply I don't think the problem is on the batch size, I've post the whole code now